# Why doesn't J2ObjC translate field with @Weak as __weak but __unsafe_unretained?

Tags: j2objc

As we know, `__unsafe_unretained` is not as safe as `__weak`, so why doesn't J2ObjC translate field with `@Weak` as `__weak` but `__unsafe_unretained`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two reasons:

1. __weak only works in ARC code, and the JRE emulation library is not built with ARC due to a noticeable performance cost.
2. In Objective C, one can test whether a __weak field has been released by testing whether it's nil. Since there's no way to do that in Java for normal references, code that depends on this behavior is platform-dependent (ie, won't work the same on Android).

J2ObjC supports the [java.lang.reflect](https://developers.google.com/j2objc/javadoc/jre/reference/java/lang/reflect/package-summary) package, so if you want a cross-platform way of using weak references, use WeakReference instead of @Weak.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that Java's `WeakReference` would be translated as `__week`, but find out it uses the translated `java/lang/ref/WeakReference` class. I look into the source of the translated `WeakReference`, but find nothing like `__weak`, how does it work under ARC? (I have cycle reference and must use `weak` to break it)

Comment: An __unsafe_unretained annotation resolves a reference cycle, which is why j2objc translates @Weak to it. The only difference __unsafe_unretained and __weak is that the latter also zeros the field when the instance is dealloc'd. That's not a problem for translated code, since when an instance is dealloc'd, the compiler shouldn't allow references to the instance's fields. If you need zeroing field behavior in your code, then use a java.lang.ref.WeakReference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have switched to `java.lang.ref.WeakReference`, but I'm a little bit curious that how does translated `java.lang.ref.WeakReference` work in objc, does it use `__weak` internally?

Comment: No, I based on the java.lang.ref support on a great article by Mike Ash: http://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-07-16-zeroing-weak-references-in-objective-c.html. Here's the support class: https://github.com/google/j2objc/blob/master/jre_emul/Classes/IOSReference.m

Comment: Clang now supports zeroing weak references in non-ARC code, with the `-fobjc-weak` flag. j2objc has been updated to always generate `__weak` annotations instead of `__unsafe_retained` for `@Weak` annotations, and its `j2objcc` script (which sets clang flags) updated to include that flag.